# error in fluent Nhibernate count(*) function

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

i have to retrive some data and count of the rows based on the criteria 
the bellow is my code snippet

```
 criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("LastUpdatedUserName"),"OperatorName")
            .Add(Projections.Property("Created"),"enrollmentdate")
            .Add(Projections.Count("NIK"), "enrollmentcount")
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("LastUpdatedUserName"))
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Created")))
            .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToEntityMap);
       var result = criteria.List<Demographic>()
```

and this snippet resulting in exception while running

here goes the exception

ex.message=`Unable to perform find[SQL: SQL not available]`
ex.innerexception=`{"The value \"System.Collections.Hashtable\" is not of type \"Indo.Id.Data.Infrastructure.Entities.Demographic\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value"}`

and the stack trace is

`at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(Object value, Type targetType)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.VerifyValueType(Object value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
   at NHibernate.Util.ArrayHelper.AddAll(IList to, IList from) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Util\ArrayHelper.cs:line 233
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1948`

type casting of the transformation to demographic will work to max extent but here in demo graphics i have approx 40 columns and i have declared a new class for holding the result like

`public class operatorenrollment
    {
       public string OperatorName { get; set; }
       public DateTime enrollmentdate { get; set; }
       public int enrollmentcount { get; set; }
    }`

can i now transform this to new class like

`NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(operatorenrollment))`

any help here is very much appriciable

thanks in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

You are using `Transformers.AliasToEntityMap`, which transforms your projection into an `IDictionary`, and trying to get back a list of `Demographic`.

Use `Transformers.AliasToBean<Demographic>()` instead.

Comment: hi now the issue turned into new one when i am trying to transform to demographic obj like the way you guided 
Could not find a setter for property 'enrollmentcount' in class 'Indo.Id.Data.Infrastructure.Entities.Demographic'
i know the property not available in demographic now can i cast the result to another object where i have only these three fields but not rest of fields like 
NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(OperatorEn))
where operatoren class is defined as below
public class operatorenrollment

Comment: {
       public string OperatorName { get; set; }
       public DateTime enrollmentdate { get; set; }
       public int enrollmentcount { get; set; }
    }